# Calling Resource sha1 is disabled! Use Resource sha256 instead Error while installing tesseract in mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tesseract

I am trying to install tesseract in mac to work with ruby gem tesseract-ocr. However, it seems like the newest version of the tesseract is not supported by the gem.
Hence I tried the following:

```
brew install 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/
8ba134eda537d2cee7daa7ebdd9f728389d9c53e/Library/Formula/tesseract.rb
```

it throws the following error:

```
Error: Calling Resource#sha1 is disabled!
Use Resource#sha256 instead.
/Users/maheshmesta/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/tesseract.rb:123:in `block 
(2 levels) in <class:Tesseract>'
```

How can I rectify this issue.

Comment: please checkout this link https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/7058